# Issues with unnumbered headers

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering

I am trying to create a subsection header without a number and without this header showing up in the TOC. So using a '*' should do the job as follows:

```
`\section*{My unnumbered header}`
```

However, this is not working. Instead, my header is shown as "*" and my intended header shows up as a new paragraph.

Any suggestions on what might be causing this problem and how I can fix it would be helpful.

I am using a class file and a set of style files provided by Georgia Tech at the following link:

http://www.gradadmiss.gatech.edu/thesis/templates.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `gatech-thesis.cls` is buggy. You will see this odd behaviour not just with `\section*` but also with `\subsection*`, and  `\subsubsection*` . The problem is that the class has (around line 2448) in the definition for `\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`:

```
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\newlinestretch{1}\normalfont\large\bfseries\itshape}
}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
  \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\newlinestretch{1}\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{%
  \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{0.25in}%
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\newlinestretch{1}\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}
}
```

and the spurious spaces after `\itshape}` and `\bfseries}` cause the problem. Add this to the preamble of your `.tex` file:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\newlinestretch{1}\normalfont\large\bfseries\itshape}% <- Important
}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
  \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\newlinestretch{1}\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}% <- Important
}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{%
  \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{0.25in}%
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\newlinestretch{1}\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}% <- Important
}
\makeatother
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{gatech-thesis}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{%
  \@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\newlinestretch{1}\normalfont\large\bfseries\itshape}% <- Important
}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{%
  \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\newlinestretch{1}\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}% <- Important
}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{%
  \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{0.25in}%
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\newlinestretch{1}\normalfont\normalsize\itshape}% <- Important
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\section*{Test section}
\subsection*{Test subsection}
\subsubsection*{Test subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please inform the class author about this bug so he can correct the class code.

Comment: I don't yet have enough point to upvote your answer, but thank you! This worked.

Comment: @SafayetAhmed You're welcome! Glad I could help.

Comment: @SafayetAhmed Now you can upvote ;)